# C# EF Can insert only one item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert, sql-server-ce

I generaeted a model from this database:

```
 [ID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
, [Prenume] nvarchar(100) NULL
, [Nume] nvarchar(100) NULL
ALTER TABLE [voluntari] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_voluntari] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UQ__voluntari__0000000000000042] ON [voluntari] ([NrLeg] ASC);
GO
```

The generated class are:

```
  public partial class voluntari
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Prenume { get; set; }
        public string Nume { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
 public partial class ValuntariEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ValuntariEntities()
            : base("name=ValuntariEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<voluntari> voluntaris { get; set; }
    }
```

The code used for insert an object into database is:

```
 Gestiune_Voluntari.ValuntariEntities ve = new ValuntariEntities();
            voluntari v = new voluntari();
            v.Nume = "Ion";
            v.Prenume = "ion";
            ve.voluntaris.Add(v);
            ve.SaveChanges();
```

In database table I can insert only one object. If I run the code above it work only one time, if i try to insert other values does not work an i get this error:

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Gestiune_Voluntari.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Florin\Documents\Proiecte programare\Gestiunevoluntari\Gestiune Voluntari\Gestiune Voluntari\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 35
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Gestiune_Voluntari.App.Main() in c:\Users\Florin\Documents\Proiecte programare\Gestiunevoluntari\Gestiune Voluntari\Gestiune Voluntari\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Inner exception is:

```
A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = voluntari,Constraint name = UQ__voluntari__0000000000000042 ]
```

the source is:

```
SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
```

It dows not work even if i specify manually an ID for the object that is not used into table. The single case when it works is when the tabel is empty.
Thank you!

UPDATE:
The problem was an other column that was setted as unique key. I forgot that.

Comment: Please show the whole table, and the NrLeg property. Why isn't it mapped into the entity? That's fundamental information for answering this question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem lies with your database because of this line:

```
[ID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
```

I would expect it to be:

```
[ID] int IDENTITY
```

With the `(1,1)` you might be calling the [IDENTITY (function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) instead of the [IDENTITY Property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)